# while creating RDS serverless through terraform throwing error waiting waiting for RDS Cluster create: unexpected state 'deleting' its deleting

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws, aws-serverless

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "postgresql" {
  cluster_identifier = "name"
  engine             = "aurora-postgresql"
  engine_version     = "14.6"
  engine_mode        = "provisioned"
  #instance_class     = "db.r6i.large"
  db_subnet_group_name    = aws_db_subnet_group.default.id
  availability_zones      = ["ap-south-1a", "ap-south-1b"]
  database_name           = var.database_name
  master_username         = var.master_username
  master_password         = var.master_password
  backup_retention_period = 7
  preferred_backup_window = "02:00-04:00"
  network_type            = "IPV4"
  port                    = 1845
  vpc_security_group_ids  = [aws_security_group.master-sg.id]
  #  vpc_security_group_ids =["sg-08cac711a39434eec"]
  skip_final_snapshot = "false"
  # final_snapshot_identifier =  local.snapshot_date
  # snapshot_identifier = "${data.aws_db_cluster_snapshot.cluster_snapshot.id}"
  enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports = ["postgresql"]
  allow_major_version_upgrade     = "true"
  enable_http_endpoint            = "true"
  serverlessv2_scaling_configuration {
    max_capacity = var.max_capacity
    min_capacity = var.min_capacity
  }
}
```

if i execute the above script getting below error issue

> waiting for RDS Cluster (name) create: unexpected state 'deleting', wanted target 'available'. last error: %!s()

we are having two accounts, its working fine and we are using it, while trying to applying it in another account, facing this issue.

Comment: Are you using aliased providers maybe?

Comment: Thanks for you reply Marko E, actullay this is my provider fileprovider "aws" {
  region  = var.region
  access_key = var.access_key
  secret_key = var.secret_key
}

Comment: And how are you specifying different AWS accounts?

Comment: actuallly we are using the script for multiple accounts, in the first i have tried in one account it is provisioned cluster, then i have copied the files to other directory, changed the keys all necressary vpc and subnets it is not working.

Comment: So you are absolutely sure you are using a different set of credentials for each of the accounts you want to apply this in?

Comment: yes Marko, we are using differenet credintals, in the ui am able to see cluster creation after few seconds its went into destroy state

Comment: Which terraform and AWS provider versions are you using?

Comment: Terraform v1.4.6, and below one is my providers configuration

terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
  }
}

Comment: Can you check the provider version in the `.terrform/providers/aws` directory?

Comment: 4.56.0 this threre .terrform/providers/aws in this directory